# Should CONNECT work in SQL*PLUS script?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I'd like to run a sqlplus script from a cron job.

I thought I could put a line like:

```
CONNECT "myuser/mypass@mydb"
```

within the script and then just execute it with:

```
sqlplus @myscript
```

However, when I do so, I get:

```
SP2-0306: Invalid Option
SP3-0157: unable to CONNECT to ORACLE after 3 attempts, exiting SQL*Plus
```

Am I misunderstanding the usage of the connect command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running `CONNECT` inside `SQL*Plus`, remove the quotes:

```
CONNECT myuser/mypass@mydb
```

They double quotes are required if you are passing the credentials as an argument to `sqlplus`:

```
sqlplus "myuser/mypass@mydb"
```

, for the shell to parse `myuser/mypass@mydb` as a single argument if you have spaces in your connection identifier or use additional options like `AS SYSDBA`.

Comment: @Wade: Does it connect from a command line with the same credentials?

Comment: @Wade: does you script fail only when run under `cron`? Could you please put `CONNECT myuser/mypass@mydb` into a `file.sql` and run `sqlplus /nolog @file.sql`?

Comment: I'm not running it under cron yet. What you describe is what I was doing.  However, the key difference is that I wasn't using the /nolog option.  With that option, it works.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the /NOLOG option.

```
sqlplus /nolog @myscript
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle 11gR2

I ran a .sql file via SQL*Plus connected initially as JOHN.  Within the file I connect as SYS and then run a GRANT.  See .sql file contents below:

connect sys/password as sysdba

GRANT EXECUTE ON DBMS_CRYPTO TO JOHN;

connect JOHN/DOE

NOTE: I don't recommend keeping the sys/password in a text file btw.

HTH